# Can subscripts be used like this?

Tags: functions, notation

I have a variable named $P$, and another three variables named $P_c$, $P_d$ and $P_u$.

Now, if I define this function: $$f(x) = x_c + x_d + x_u$$
Is it correct to say that: $$f(P) = P_c + P_d + P_u$$

I'm really not sure if I subscripts can be used like this. If not, how could I define the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function $f(x)=x_c+x_d+x_u$ doesn't make sense unless you describe how $x_c$, $x_d$, and $x_u$ are related to $x$, for any $x$. However, if you are able to describe them, then this is fine.

For example, if $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and you define $x_c$, $x_d$, and $x_u$ to be the three components of the vector (i.e., $x = \left[\begin{array}{c} x_c \\ x_d \\ x_u\end{array}\right]$), then $f$ makes sense, because for any $x$, you have described what $x_c$, $x_d$, and $x_u$ are.

Comment: I get it, thanks for your help!